# From PDF to MGF

Tags: probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

I am given a PDF

$f_y(y) = 4ye^{-2y}$ for $0<y<\infty$

and have to compute the mgf.

So I did

$M_y(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{ty}4ye^{-2y}}$

Which solves to

$M_y(t) = -\frac{4}{{(t-2)}^2}$

Yet according to my book it's

$M_y(t) = \frac{4}{{(t-2)}^2}$

Am I wrong? I redid my calculations a few times.

**EDIT:** I am an idiot, forgot the $-$ for the lower bound of the integral...

It is solved and can be closed.

Comment: An MGF will always be nonnegative. Don't forget your minus signs when evaluating the antiderivative.

Comment: I am an idiot, forgot the $-$ for the lower bound of the integral...